# Sparsity regularization for eigenvectors

Tags: regularization, sparse, eigenvalues

One way to think about finding the eigenvectors of a matrix $A$ is that they are the critical points of the functional $\vec x^\top A \vec x$ subject to $\|\vec x\|_2=1$.  To regularize this problem, it is easy enough to ask that we minimize $\vec x^\top A \vec x+\varepsilon\|\vec x\|_2^2$, since this corresponds to finding eigenvectors of $A+\varepsilon I$.

Is there a way to replace $\|\vec x\|_2^2$ with an $L^1$ norm to encourage sparsity in $\vec x$?  What sort of computation would result?  Is it tractable?

Comment: By the way, I can find "sparse PCA" methods -- can any of these be used to find sparse _minimum_ rather than maximum eigenvalues?